# Got socket error trying to find package source_span at https://pub.dev : Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool

Tags: flutter, dart, pub.dev

> Got socket error trying to find package source_span at
> https://pub.dev. Error (69): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool.
> Retrying in five seconds (6 tries left)  Running pub upgrade Resolving
> dependencies this message appeared today and a "initializing the
> flutter SDK . This may take a few minutes" and I tried many times lot
> of answers but still the same thing

I tried some answer from here but nothing changed,
I tried to delete the cache file in flutter/pin ,
tried to run flutter doctor flutter clean, flutter upgrade
and every time i run flutter doctor gives me

> "C:\Users\alnag>flutter -- version Building flutter tool ... Running
> pub upgrade ... Resolving dependencies ... (4.6s) ^CTerminate batch
> job (Y/N)? y C: \Users\alnag>flutter doctor Building flutter tool ...
> Running pub upgrade ... Resolving dependencies ... (2.8s)